# How to convert images to pixels values and store them in a text file?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a folder with `n` grayscale 48*48 images.

I want to extract pixel values of each image apart and save it in a seperate text file (I'll have `n` text files).

I have tried this :

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('a.png')

pixels = list(im.getdata())
width, height = im.size 
pixels = [pixels[i * width:(i + 1) * width] for i in xrange(height)]
np.savetxt("pixel_data.txt", pixels, delimiter=" ")
```

But I'm getting values like this: `1.460000000000000000e+02` `1.500000000000000000e+02` `1.520000000000000000e+02`.

I want to have 48 columns x 48 lines in every text file with pixel values between 0-255.

Sample image:

[image: sample image]

How can I do this with python?

Comment: Can you link us to a sample image?

Comment: Those values are between 0-255 but are floats in scientific notation, have you tried converting the values in ``pixels`` to ints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those numbers are correct. You are using the `np.savetxt` method which converts the numbers to scientific notation by default. To save them as ints I believe you would do:

```
np.savetxt("pixel_data.txt", pixels, fmt='%d', delimiter=" ")
```

Comment: I must have 48 columns * 48 lines but i'm getting 325 lines and 1027 columns. What is wrong ?

Comment: are you sure your image is 48 x 48?

Comment: It was a mistake. Thank you for reponse fmt='%d' was all i needed.